# HTML form with dropdownlist using jsp code

Tags: html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have this form used to insert data into a database.
I want to change one value selecting from a dropdownlist connected to a mysql database.

This is the form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <form onsubmit="return checkempty(form1)" action="Data_insert.jsp" method="post" name="form1">
      <table id="table" width="25%">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="emp_name">Name:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="emp_name" id="emp_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="emp_country">Country: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="emp_country" id="emp_country"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p><br>
      </p>
    </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But to fill the country I want to use a jsp getting the data from Mysql DB with a jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%ResultSet resultset =null;%>

<HTML>

<%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root","1234");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ;
        resultset =statement.executeQuery("select country_id, country_name from country") ;
%>

<center>
    <h1> Drop down box or select element</h1>
        <select>
        <option value="0">Select Country</option>
            <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
                <option value="<%=resultset.getInt("country_id")%>"> <%= resultset.getString("country_name")%></option>
            <% } %>
        </select>
</center>

<%
//**Should I input the codes here?**
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             out.println("wrong entry"+e);
        }
%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Both codes work independent. My question is how can I integrate the Country dropdown list into the form.

Thanks !

Comment: Put your all code i.e :  `inputs` as well `select` under `<form></form>` tags.

Comment: Thanks Swati!! I am quite beginner and yet do not understand ...

Let's say I put the jsp code into a file: CountryDropdown.jsp
How can I get the result of CountryDropdown.jsp into this line of the HTML:
<td><input type="text" name="emp_country" id="emp_country"></td>

So that the value of the whole form will be passed to the action="Data_insert.jsp".
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve above in following ways :

**1)** . Put all your code in same page and use `jquery/js` to assign value of `<select>` to your `<input..>` like below :

```js
//onchange of select this will execute
$("select").on("change", function() {
  //getting value of select-box
  var value = $(this).val();
  //assign value to input with id="emp_country"
  $("#emp_country").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- put your db connection code here-->

Select-box: 
<select>
  <option value="0">Select Country</option>
  <!--put your option code here-->
  <option value="something">Something</option>

</select>


<!--put catch block here-->

<form onsubmit="return checkempty(form1)" action="Data_insert.jsp" method="post" name="form1">
  <table id="table" width="25%">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="emp_name">Name:  </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="emp_name" id="emp_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="emp_country">Country: </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="emp_country" id="emp_country"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p><br>
  </p>
</form>
```

**2)**.In `CountryDropdown.jsp` put your `select-box` inside `<form></form>` with a submit  button like below :

```
<form method="post" action="Yourformpagename">
  <%
   <!--connection code->
%>

    <center>
      <h1> Drop down box or select element</h1>
      <select name="country">
        <option value="0">Select Country</option>
        <%  while(resultset.next()){ %>
          <option value="<%=resultset.getInt(" country_id ")%>">
            <%= resultset.getString("country_name")%>
          </option>
          <% } %>
      </select>
    </center>

    <%
<!--catch block code here-->
%>
      <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

And then get it in your form page like below:

```
<input type="text" name="emp_country" id="emp_country" value="${param.country}"/>
```

Comment: Both ways worked for me. I prefer option #1 as I can integrate in the form. Again thank you !!!

Comment: glad i help :) try to set this answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Hi Swati, I tried before but maybe as I am a new joiner it does not reflect my vote?